# Wordpress: Can I call a function after a link is clicked and use a shortcut?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, shortcode

I try to delete some entries from my database after a link ("Delete") is ticked. I would like to do it via shortcode. Is this possible? BTW: I am really a php noob. Be lenient with me :)

```
add_shortcode('my-delete', 'my_delete_func');
function my_delete_func($atts){
extract(shortcode_atts(array('id' => '', 'label' => ''), $atts));

   // some code to delete my SQL entries

   return '<a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'">' . $label . '</a>';
}
```

This does obviously not work. "some code" will be executed if I just call the shortcode inside WP.
There must be a way, as other shortcodes do exactly this: generate a link and if I click this link some functions do this and that. AJAX?

Any help would be great.
Thank you

Comment: As a workaround: I can use a parameter in my link like  return '<a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'?del">' . $label . '</a>'; and than wrap my "some code" in an if than statement: $param = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; if (!isset($param)) { /*di it*/} Quick 'n' dirty.

Comment: The way your comment sounds is that you do not check whether it's a privileged user (logged in) allowed to delete this specific content and prevent CSRF attacks on this ?del link. You should first find a decent AJAX tutorial and read up on generating and checking nonces for authenticated users (don't use a `nopriv` action). Next, you should limit the delete privilege to the owner of the post and administrators.

Comment: @Damocles: Thank you. However, as this is a internal project, I truly believe I can trust me ;) Second: To sanitize, or checking some conditions is not my concerning right now. This is just to understand how to do one specific thing.